# How can we train multiple models sequentially with TensorFlow.js

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow.js

**1. What I want to do**

I have 2 models and want to train 1 model at a time and switch training after 1epoch of training of a model.

- model1 is on training, model2 is waiting
- SWITCH after a epoch of model1's training
- model1 is waiting, model2 is on training
- SWITCH after a epoch of model2's training
- ,,,(loop until both model has enough performance)

Parameter of model.fit() has onEpochEnd() function as callback, so I think I can use async/await and Promise with this onEpochEnd(), but I don't come up with working code as I expect.

**2. Some Code**

```js
class Runner {
  queue: Promise[];
  async waitAnotherModel() {
    // ????
    // wait until a learning epoch of another model ends

    // bellow is my idea but it doesn't work as I expect
    const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (this.queue.length > 0) {
        const next = this.queue.shift();
        resolve(next);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
    this.queue.push(p);
  }
}

const runner = new Runner();

model1.fit(Xs, Ys, {
  epochs: 10,
  validationData: [xsVal, ysVal],
  callbacks: { onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => await runner.waitAnotherModel() },
});

model2.fit(Xs, Ys, {
  epochs: 10,
  validationData: [xsVal, ysVal],
  callbacks: { onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => await runner.waitAnotherModel() },
});
```

**3. What I've tried for now**

- Coding
  I believe Runner.waitAnotherModel() needs async/await and Promise,
  but I don't come up with proper way to use resolve() to switch model to be trained in a sequential order.
- Pause/Resume training
  If I can save/restore everything on learning, then I can pause/resume training.
  However especially with Adam optmizer, I can't save/restore training as long as I know.
- Rich Machine Resource
  If I have rich machine resources, then I can train each model on each resource.
  but please don't expect this ;)

Comment: What is the purpose of training in this manner over training both models sequentially?